# User was removed gave me -15 reputation

Tags: support

I just received -15 reputation points for some action called *User was removed*. What? That does not make sense.

More in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: tl;dr: When a low-activity user is removed, all their votes are removed as well - hence why you lose rep when that happens.

Comment: Thanks! I now also this is a duplicate of the first item listed in the *Related* list. I'll flag it myself.